# jQuery code to fill entire body with '.'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to fill entire body of HTML document with '.'(a dot). So that my HTML document looks like a mesh. Here is what I've achieved: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh1menj0/) When I change `display:block` in child class, all the dots get vertically aligned. I want to achieve a square grid of dots which span over the entire body of HTML document with each dot within child class. Is there any way I can do it?

**HTML**

`<div id="main"></div>`

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    $("#main").append("<div class='child'>.</div>");
  }
});
```

**CSS**

```
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.child {
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: in `.child` class delete `display: inline;` and insert `float:left;`

Comment: You may have found a solution but please don't use this in the real world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting it as an inline-block.

Note that this might need more nodes than 1000. It might be better to set #main with a background image of dot and make it repeat. It will have better performance (unless you need to do something with the dots).

Answer (score 2):

Add float: left;

```css
.child{
    width:2px;
    height:2px;
    float: left;
}
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh1menj0/2/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all of your dots are rendered as one long word. So you need to set word-wrap, which is well supported according to this article: http://www.impressivewebs.com/word-wrap-css3/

Here is the fix:
CSS

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#main{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    line-height: 4px; /* optional */
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
        $("#main").append(".");
    }
});
```